# GA transaction code on page - how to get items IDs and revenue from it?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So on the "thank you" page we have the following piece of code (just it, nothing else with any info about order contents):

```
jQuery(function() {
if (typeof ga == 'function') {
    ga('require', 'ecommerce');
    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': '900009781',
        'affiliation': 'Shopname',
        'revenue': '9886',
        'shipping': '0',
        'tax': '0',
        'currency': 'RUB'
    });
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '900009781',
        'name': 'product name',
        'sku': '721',
        'category': 'category',
        'price': '258',
        'quantity': '6'
    });
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '900009781',
        'name': 'product name',
        'sku': '303',
        'category': 'category',
        'price': '1159',
        'quantity': '3'
    });
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '900009781',
        'name': 'product name',
        'sku': '11265',
        'category': 'category',
        'price': '4861',
        'quantity': '1'
    });
    ga('ecommerce:send');
}
});
```

Is it even possible to get a list of item IDs from it?

Comment: Short of grabbing the contents of that script block as text and then regex the heck out of it this is probably not possible. It might help if you gave some context - how do you want to get the data? I.e. If you can edit Javascript in the page then why not simply change the code to make the variables accessible in other functions (e.g. by storing the products in an array and then loop through the array for your addItem calls) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Well, this is the problem - I do not have an access to website's code. The only thing I have is pieace of code above.